# Drag and drop Angular 7 Material CDK

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Hola tengo un problema al realizar drag and drop, os pongo en situación necesito crear grupos de usuarios en cual existen terapeutas y pacientes, solo puede haber 1 terapeuta por grupo y pacientes todos los que quiera, pero no pueden repetirse...

Necesito que solo se pueda arrastrar 1 item y si intento arrastrar otro no me deje.

También me gustaría preguntar como puedo hacer para insertar los datos en la base de datos mysql.

```html
<div class="card-top-grupos">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Grupo de usuarios 1</span>
        <div class="card-header-actions save-button">
        <a href="" class="card-header-action" target="_blank">
        <small class="text-muted" (click)='saveGroup()'><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> GUARDAR</small>
        </a>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="terapeutas-box" cdkDropList #pendingList1="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="terapeutasgrupouno" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList3]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <div class="grupo-terapeuta" *ngFor="let item of terapeutasgrupouno" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag><i class="fas fa-user-md fa-icon"></i> {{item}}</div>
          <p class="dragdrop" *ngIf="terapeutasgrupouno == ''"><i class="fas fa-user-md fa-icon"></i> Arrastra un terapeuta</p>
        </div>

        <div class="pacientes-box" cdkDropList #pendingList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="pacientesgrupouno" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList3]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <div class="grupo-paciente" *ngFor="let item of pacientesgrupouno" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag><i class="fas fa-user-injured fa-icon"></i> {{item}}</div>
           <p class="dragdrop" *ngIf="pacientesgrupouno == ''"><i class="fas fa-user-injured fa-icon"></i> Añade pacientes</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- SEGUNDO BLOQUE -->
    <div class="card card-bottom">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Grupo de usuarios 2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" cdkDropList #pendingList2="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="grupo2" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList3]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div class="grupo-paciente" *ngFor="let item of grupo2" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag><i class="fas fa-user-injured fa-icon"></i> {{item}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- SEGUNDA COLUMNA -->
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <!-- PRIMER BLOQUE -->
    <div class="card card-bottom">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Pacientes</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" cdkDropList #pacientesList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="pacientes" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList, pendingList2]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group has-search">
              <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="paciente" *ngFor="let item of pacientes" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag><i class="fas fa-user-injured fa-icon"></i> {{item}} </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- TERCERA COLUMNA -->
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <!-- PRIMER BLOQUE -->
    <div class="card card-bottom">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Terapeutas</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" cdkDropList #terapeutasList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="terapeutas" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList1]" (cdkDropListDropped)="droptrash($event)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group has-search">
              <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="terapeuta" *ngFor="let item of terapeutas" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag><i class="fas fa-user-md fa-icon"></i> {{item}} </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Ese es mi html y mi componente es el siguiente:

```
 papelera = [];
pacientesgrupouno = [];
  terapeutasgrupouno = [];
  grupo2 = [];

    terapeutas = [
    'Ana lopez',
    'Erica sanchez',
    'Marta Sanchez',
    'Mario Gonzales',
    ];

    pacientes = [
    'Emilio Escobar',
    'Daniel Bobis',
    'Gustavo Verdejo',
    'Pablo Ramos'
    ];

  droptrash(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
    console.log('dropped Event', `> dropped '${event.item.data}' into '${event.container.id}'`);
    moveItemInArray(
      event.container.data, 
      event.previousIndex, 
      event.currentIndex);
  } else {
      console.log('dropped Event', `> dropped '${event.item.data}' into '${event.container.id}'`);
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
    console.log('dropped Event',`> dropped '${event.item.data}' into '${event.container.id}'`);
    moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data, 
        event.previousIndex, 
        event.currentIndex);
  } else {
      console.log('dropped Event',`> dropped '${event.item.data}' into '${event.container.id}'`);
      copyArrayItem(
          event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
```

Les dejo una captura para que puedan apreciar a que me refiero muchas gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En los métodos donde controlas el drop puedes checkear lógica adicional como la que planteas.

Por ejemplo:

```
      drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
      if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
        console.log('dropped Event',`> dropped '${event.item.data}' into '${event.container.id}'`);
        moveItemInArray(
            event.container.data, 
            event.previousIndex, 
            event.currentIndex);
      } else {
          console.log('dropped Event',`> dropped '${event.item.data}' into '${event.container.id}'`);

        const elementoOrigen = event.container.data[event.previousIndex];
        if(event.container.data.find(element => element === elementoOrigen)) 
         { 
            return; // No se hace nada, si no funciona prueba event.preventDefault();
         }
        else 
         {
          copyArrayItem(
              event.previousContainer.data,
            event.container.data,
            event.previousIndex,
            event.currentIndex);
        }}
      }
```

`event.container.data` y `event.previousContainer.data` son los arrays de cada zona y puedes iterar sobre ellos como prefieras.